# Hibernate Criteria OR Restriction - fetch list if either one or both columns value is 1

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

My Table structure is as follows:

[image]

Can someone help with the following criteria query:

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(getEntity(), "b");
c.add(Restrictions.in("b.isTwitterVerified", 1));
or // b.isFbVerified =1// something like this
return c.list();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should return what your after:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getEntity(), "b"); 
Criterion isTwitterVerified = Restrictions.eq("b.isTwitterVerified", 1);
Criterion isFbVerified = Restrictions.eq("b.isFbVerified ", 1);
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(isTwitterVerified , isFbVerified ));

return criteria.list();
```

On the side.. the `in` restriction that you tried to use: `Restrictions.in`.. this would have its place when you would like to verify a certain field against many values (1,3,5 for example).

Comment: Hey, right answer, which I've upvoted, but SO prefers a bit of verbage around the answers to explain what's happening and where the OP was going wrong. In this case you could say something about the boolean condition restrictions.

Comment: Agree.. more info added